# Where can i find aircraft blueprints for study purpose?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-development

I'm a 3D artist and i want to start my new project. I'm going to create an exact model of the Embraer 190 aircraft. I need this for my graduation project at the university (I chose such a project, there is much more than just modeling, but this is the first step). But at the zero step, I was faced with the fact that there are simply no free blueprints in the public domain. There are all sorts of approximate schemes of the aircraft, but they can hardly be called accurate. Even in the manual from Embraer, only exemplary drawings.
Where can I find such things? I am ready to buy them, if necessary.

Comment: Not sure about the blueprints, but some 3D models already exist... if it can be of any help: https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/search/?q=Embraer%20190

Comment: Even more detailed models exist. For example: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-embraer-erj-190-klm/785574
But i still want to create it by myself :)

Comment: The downvotes this is getting are unwarranted in my opinion. The question might be a tad naive but it is valid, even if the answer were to be "nowhere".

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please note that shopping and resource location questions are [off-topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, but do stick around.

Answer (score 4):

Fifteen euros gets you what you need here: https://www.the-blueprints.com/vectordrawings/show/1750/embraer_190/

This one is six euros: http://www.lulu.com/shop/elodie-roux/3-view-drawing-plan-3-vues-embraer-190/ebook/product-20233147.html

Comment: Thank you, sir! I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

High level drawings for familiarization manuals might be what you are looking for, try looking for training material for the ground crew, or familiarization courses for engineers.

Also you lose nothing by reaching out to the manufacturer itself, while it is unlikely you'll get a positive response, it costs little to try.